# Can't find module attribute, even though it exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very strange python problem with the built in http module. It successfully imports, but the http.client attribute does not exist?
It is there in the python docs and my brother runs the code perfectly. It does not work for me though, neither on my linux laptop or my mac!
Been having this issue for a couple of days now and really need it fixed!

the exact error message is:

```
except (http.client.ResponseNotReady, http.client.CannotSendRequest, http.client.BadStatusLine) as e:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

When removing this exception, there are just more of them in this file, so i can't just simply remove that exception anyway

Because i could not find the root of this problem, i started probing for the http module folder and find the client.py

When typing help(http) in the python interpreter, it responds this:

```
PACKAGE CONTENTS
    client
    cookiejar
    cookies
    server

FILE
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/http/__init__.py
```

Well, i know that the help command info is automatically generated and those packages might have been removed or something. So i went to the http directory and did a "ls -l" giving me this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     38  6 Apr 21:29 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel    408  4 May 21:29 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  44644  6 Apr 21:29 client.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  75973  6 Apr 21:29 cookiejar.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  20360  6 Apr 21:29 cookies.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  44788  6 Apr 21:29 server.py
```

There's the client.py i have been looking for! and it even has lots of code in it so wouldn't it be accessible?

Neither is it possible to just try to access it in the python interpreter!

```
>>> import http
>>> http.client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what version of python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You imported `http`. But did you import `http.client` as well?

This is necessary, as it depends on the package's `__init__.py` if the sub-modules are imported or not.

Comment: The funny thing is that he had this issue for days now, and he gets the right answer 30 seconds after he's asked the question here.

Comment: Thank you! it worked!

Strangely it worked on my brothers machine as i said, so i didn't think it had to do with the code